# gettting "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address" all of a sudden

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, sendmail

It worked for a while, I sent some emails to myself. But when I tried the code later on it stopped working.
I am using this code in a code behind file of an asp.net page. The page is hosted on a hosting server.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.Host = "smtp.mundoazx.com.br";

client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail","mypwd");
//error line below
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("administration", "diegoazx23@yahoo.com.br", "test", "test body");

mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

client.Send(mm);
```

Comment: `administration` is not a valid email address.

Comment: Yes it worked! I changed that setting many many times.  When I save the files Visual Studio doesn't sync with the ftp version. And I have to work with the ftp files directly because I'm using the smtp server from my hosting company.

Comment: I replaced "administration" for an email account that I created as part of my hosting service. something like this: "administration@mydomain.com". That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of your `MailMessage` instance must be your email adress, like in `System.Net.NetworkCredential`